# MySQL export/import data consistency problem

Tags: mysql

Currently experiencing an issue whereby I am exporting a MySQL structure and data from a server into a sql file, ready for importing into a local database.

When importing the sql file into a local database, numerous records are changing dramatically. The columns in question tend to be of type bit(1).

The local setup uses the following versions Apache 2.2.17, PHP 5.3.5 and MySQL 5.5.8.

The server is currently using MySQL 5.1.56.

Any ideas what can be done to rectify this scenario?

Comment: maybe a default value changed? could you give us the sql file and the value after/before please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the --hex-blob parameter with the **mysqldump** utility when obtaining the sql dump.